With rsync, why '-t' negates '--compare-dest'?
In the following sequence, I can't see why the 4th case would copy foo.xml. The -t option seems to negate the --compare-dest option. Why is that?
tree data
echo "-[1]----------------------------------------------"
rsync -rvn --size-only --ignore-times data/old/ data/new/
echo "-[2]----------------------------------------------"
rsync -rvn --size-only --ignore-times --compare-dest=$PWD/data/old/ data/new/ data/delta/
echo "-[3]----------------------------------------------"
rsync -rvntO --size-only --ignore-times data/old/ data/new/
echo "-[4]----------------------------------------------"
rsync -rvntO --size-only --ignore-times --compare-dest=$PWD/data/old/ data/new/ data/delta/

Output result:
(The two XML files have the same content, but not the same modification time.)
data
├── delta
├── new
│   └── foo.xml
└── old
    └── foo.xml

3 directories, 2 files
-[1]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list

sent 64 bytes  received 12 bytes  152,00 bytes/sec
total size is 2.055  speedup is 27,04 (DRY RUN)
-[2]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list

sent 64 bytes  received 12 bytes  152,00 bytes/sec
total size is 2.055  speedup is 27,04 (DRY RUN)
-[3]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list

sent 67 bytes  received 19 bytes  172,00 bytes/sec
total size is 2.055  speedup is 23,90 (DRY RUN)
-[4]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list
foo.xml

sent 71 bytes  received 19 bytes  180,00 bytes/sec
total size is 2.055  speedup is 22,83 (DRY RUN)

(Fun fact: "XX bytes sent" messages do not always show the same value between two runs)
Output when adding the "--itemize-changes, -i" option:
-[1]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list

sent 59 bytes  received 12 bytes  142,00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0,06 (DRY RUN)
-[2]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list

sent 64 bytes  received 12 bytes  152,00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0,05 (DRY RUN)
-[3]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list
.f..t...... foo.txt

sent 66 bytes  received 19 bytes  170,00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0,05 (DRY RUN)
-[4]----------------------------------------------
sending incremental file list
cf..t...... foo.txt

sent 71 bytes  received 19 bytes  180,00 bytes/sec
total size is 4  speedup is 0,04 (DRY RUN)


Add the -i flag to see what is triggering the transfer, and update the question to include the new data field in the results. Remember though that when you're copying from local to local, as in this instance, rsync tends to disable almost all of its optimisations and revert to simple copies like cp

If I now understand things correctly, the important point is that cases 3 and 4 update foo.xml for the same reason: change its timestamp to reflect that of data/new/foo.xml. This leads to an unexpected file copy in the 4th case, but that's just rsync trying to comply with the contradictory request of ignoring time changes but also updating timestamps. Am I right?

The documentation does warn of this (man rsync under --times), "This tells rsync to transfer modification times along with the files and update them  on  the remote  system.   Note  that if this option is not used, the optimization that excludes files that have not been modified cannot be effective; in other words, a missing -t  (or  -a)  will cause  the next transfer to behave as if it used --ignore‐times (-I), causing all files to be updated"

The fourth example is triggered by c, which is explained that "a local change/creation is occurring for the item (such as the creation of a directory or the changing of a symlink, etc.)", as well as -t
